# How to get provider name or provider code?

Tags: android, provider

I want to make a simple android apps for myself. This time I want to make app that will allow me to check my pulse. 
My question is how can I get the provider name or provider code in activity? 
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use TelephonyManager to get provider name, look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```